# I am facing error in creating folder and file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

write_file()

mkdir()

both are not working and not creating my file and folder inside my development folder.
what should i do ?

I want to create svg files inside folder through loop in controller but the folder is not creating and also the file is not creating event after including

all helpers and libraries

i have included file, url helpers and directory helper and ftp library

please help me to come out of this error.

Comment: if you are using codeigniter then why don't u use codeigniter file related functions?

Comment: you should also check about folder permissions to create files into it

Comment: i checked it ... the thing is i am able to create the folder in root directory but not able to created inside other directories like assets/

Comment: i used file related functions only.

Comment: After checking the file permissions it working !!! was issue on hosting side